# Использование bind в tkinter в классе

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, gui, binding

Хочу реализовать нечто такое, но ничего не выходит. 
Подскажите, пожалуйста, в чем проблема?

```
import tkinter as tk

window = tk.Tk()


class App:
    def __int__(self):
        window.bind('<w>', self.q)

    def q(self, e):
        print(e)


App()
window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Ничего не выходит потому что опечатка в названии метода: должно быть `__init__`, а не `__int__`. Ну и события `<w>` не существует. А так код рабочий: https://i.stack.imgur.com/nJrC7.png

Comment: Ого. В следующий раз буду внимательней. Благодарю.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
import tkinter as tk


class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)
        
#        window.bind('<w>', self.q)
        
        self.label = tk.Label(text='Наведите на меня курсор')
        self.label.place(x=65, y=1)
        self.label.bind('<Enter>', self.label_enter)
        self.label.bind('<Leave>', self.label_leave)


    def label_enter(self, event):
        print(f'Вы навели курсор на label: {event}')
        
    def label_leave(self, event):
        print(f'Вы покинули label: {event}')


if __name__ == '__main__':
    window = tk.Tk()
    window.geometry('260x130')
    app = App(window)
    app.pack()
    window.mainloop()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Благодарю, сейчас попробую под свою задачу подстроить.

Comment: А вы можете рассказать, как работают строчки? 
class App(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master):
        super().__init__(master)

Comment: Под свою задачу получилось подстроить. Но понять смысл указанных мною выше строчек я не могу.

Comment: @qwerty, пожалуйста, погуглите фразу `tkinter ООП` и почитаете что-то такое https://pythonru.com/uroki/oop-v-prilozhenii-tkinter-tkinter , если что-то будет не понятно - зададите новый вопрос. Если мой ответ помог вам, то не забудьте пометить как правильный, если вы не знаете, как это сделать, проверьте https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour

Comment: Понял вас. Благодарю.